# What are the differences between the pine script script functions

Tags: pine-script, indicator

Please consider the following 2 pine script (v4) functions

```
rng_filt(x, rng_, n)=>
    r          = rng_
    var rfilt  = array.new_float(2, x)
    array.set(rfilt, 1, array.get(rfilt, 0))
    if x - r > array.get(rfilt, 1)
        array.set(rfilt, 0, x - r)
    if x + r < array.get(rfilt, 1)
        array.set(rfilt, 0, x + r)
    rng_filt1 = array.get(rfilt, 0)
    
    hi_band   = rng_filt1 + r
    lo_band   = rng_filt1 - r
    rng_filt  = rng_filt1
    [hi_band, lo_band, rng_filt]


rng_filt2(x, rng_, n)=>
    r          = rng_
    var rfilt  = array.new_float(2, x)

    rng_filt1 = x
    if x - r > x
        rng_filt1 := x - r
    if x + r < x
        rng_filt1 :=  x + r

    hi_band2   = rng_filt1 + r
    lo_band2   = rng_filt1 - r
    rng_filt2  = rng_filt1
    [hi_band2, lo_band2, rng_filt2]
```

The first implementation `rng_filt` is part of one of the trading view indicators.

The `rng_filt2` is a function I wrote aimed to make the former simpler and more readble for the purpose of converting it to c#.

The original function defines a 2 items array `rfilt`, both intialized with the input `x`.

Then the `array.set(rfilt, 1, array.get(rfilt, 0))` assigned the array[0] into array[1], basically doing nothing.

Then two if statements, both comapre againts array[1] which is actually the input argument `x`. For both, if the condition is true the array[0] is set to the condition value

So:

```
if x - r > array.get(rfilt, 1)
    array.set(rfilt, 0, x - r)


if x + r < array.get(rfilt, 1)
    array.set(rfilt, 0, x + r)
```

Can be converted into

```
rng_filt1 = x
if x - r > x
    rng_filt1 := x - r

if x + r < x
    rng_filt1 :=  x + r
```

If none of the conditions are true array[0] == x as intialized.
So in the 2nd implementation, `rng_filt1` is initialized to `x`

This is how these functions are called.

```
[h_band, l_band, filt] = rng_filt(rng_src, rng_size(rng_src, rng_qty, rng_per), rng_per)
[h_band2, l_band2, filt2] = rng_filt2(rng_src, rng_size(rng_src, rng_qty, rng_per), rng_per)
```

When comparing for example

```
if h_band = h_band2
```

The result is `false`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then the array.set(rfilt, 1, array.get(rfilt, 0)) assigned the
> array[1] into array[0], basically doing nothing.

This is not correct. It does something. It assigns the second item in the array into the first one as you said. In the next two if statements, it could modify the first item of this array. So, on the next bar when it calls this function, array[0] could have a different value which would get copied to array[1].

Hence, the below statement is also not correct:

> Then two if statements, both comapre againts array[1] which is
> actually the input argument x.

Comment: Not sure i understand. For each bar **a new** array is being created and intialized.  Isn't it?

Comment: No. The array is defined with the `var` keyword. That means it will only be created and initilazed once.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the post, one you quoted. _Then the array.set(rfilt, 1, array.get(rfilt, 0)) assigned the array[1] into array[0]_ it should be the opposite. _assigned the array[0] into array[1]_. I fixed the post maybe you should consider do the same, for future readers.